# MySQLSelect Statement

Tags: mysql, database

How can I filter for all the price in my SQL database? where price field contains `,` and `$` values. `Eg.$16,500,$1.00,$12,400`

```
select [colm1], [price],[colm2] from [db] where price BETWEEN 1 AND 500 limit 100 \G;
```

The above query produces output for price greater than $500.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Consider changing price to a non-text column.

Comment: Please add the ddl.

Comment: can you please share column value for 3-4 rows

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  `[colm1]` sure looks like SQL Server to me.

Comment: _Don't_ store your prices as text formatted values, store them as double numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `replace()` function

```
select [colm1], [price],[colm2] 
 from [db]
   where cast(replace(replace(price,'$',''),',','') as unsigned) BETWEEN 1 AND 500 limit 100
```